# Error 415 Unsupported media Type con cliente en AngularJS y Java

Tags: java, angularjs, csv, jersey

Me encuentro desde hace un par de días con el siguiente error del lado del cliente desarrollado en AngularJS el error generado es el siguiente:

> 415 (Unsopported Media Type)

el código es el siguiente:

Formulario:

```
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-offset-3 col-sm-6 col-md-offset-4 col-md-4 text-center form-group">
            <input type="file" id="csvFileInput" file-input="csvFile" accept=".csv" ng-model="csvFile" />
            <button ng-click="uploadFile()">Cargar CSV</button>
 </div>
```

En el controlador tengo lo siguiente:

```
    app.controller('AdminController', ['$scope', '$http','$window','$location', 'filterFilter','UserFactory', function($scope, $http, $window, $location,filterFilter,UserFactory) {
$scope.uploadFile = function() {
        console.log("Entro")
        var fileInput = document.getElementById('csvFileInput');
    
        var file = fileInput.files[0];
        $scope.csvFile = null;
        
        if (file) {
          var formData = new FormData();
          formData.append('csvFile', file)
          $http.post('/xxx-services/rest/afiliado/cargueBloqueoAfiliados', formData, {
            transformRequest: angular.identity,
            headers: { 'Content-Type': undefined }
          }).then(function(response) {
            // Manejar la respuesta del servidor aquí
            console.log(response.data);
          }).catch(function(error) {
            // Manejar errores en la solicitud al servidor
            console.error(error);
          });
        }else{
            console.log("No Existe")
        }
      };
    
}])
.directive('fileInput', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
            element.on('change', function(event) {
                scope.$apply(function() {
                    scope[attrs.fileInput] = event.target.files[0];
                });
            });
        }
    };
});
```

Nota: la directiva la agregué recientemente y no estoy seguro si funciona bien

Y en el Backend en Java:

```
 @POST
    @Path("/cargueBloqueoAfiliados")
    @Consumes(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON + ";charset=utf-8")
    public String cargueBloqueoAfiliados(
            @Context HttpHeaders headers, 
            @Context HttpServletRequest requestContext,
            @FormDataParam("csvFile") InputStream fileStream,
            @FormDataParam("csvFile") FormDataContentDisposition fileDetalle
            ) throws Exception {
```

pom.xml:

```
   <dependency>
<groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
<artifactId>jersey-media-multipart</artifactId>
<version>2.38</version>
</dependency>
```

Finalmente las cabeceras de la solicitud son:

Accept:

```
application/json, text/plain, */*
```

Accept-Encoding:

```
gzip, deflate, br
```

Accept-Language:

```
es,es-ES;q=0.9,en;q=0.8,en-GB;q=0.7,en-US;q=0.6
```

Connection:

```
keep-alive
```

Content-Length:

```
10119
```

Content-Type:

```
multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundary8J49QQx1TgK2JwDB
```

Cookie:

```
session=vfdESDc8NgUziiHS9v9LWp+ue7A+X1651SdMF5wbDX8AYLnfhIxb8oYEmMLWI3vGZCEp1w4Jb2HVU0cyFIbaN+cEflVhy1F5ze0Yo7
```

Muchas gracias.

Comment: no crees que tenga que ver la parte que dice `'Content-Type': undefined`?

Comment: @RuslanLópez Según he visto, se puede dejar indefinido para que el navegador lo defina

Comment: ¿Y ya verificaste que el navegador realmente lo esté definiendo?

Comment: @RuslanLópez Si, allí en la formulación de la pregunta he añadido las cabeceras y pues veo que si: Content-Type: multipart/form-data;

Comment: Ok, entonces... intenta usando `@FormDataParam("csvFile") FormDataBodyPart fileStream`